# can anyone suggest some good projects in machine learning or data sciences?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, machine-learning-model

I've just completed a course in machine learning(supervised and unsupervised learning both) and data sciences Using PYTHON. i also know about web scraping and modules such as pandas ,numpy .Can anyone please suggest some good projects related to these topics. Especially with neural networks. It will be appreciated a lot if the projects help me strengthen my resume for job placements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best platform to start by doing ur journey in ML world would be https://www.kaggle.com/

You would have a large array of projects from beginner to advanced and to the competitive level to choose from.

There is also a large community that is there to help and seek ideas from, I would just advise to try it out!